# Check if dictionary key contains any of another dictionary's keys and print matching pairs

Tags: python, dictionary, key, contains, key-value

My question is probably quite simple, however I have been puzzling over numerous methods and cannot seem to find an efficient answer without using many for loops.

I have a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'full_name1' : 1, 
           'full_name2' : 2,
           'full_name3' : 3}
```

I also have this dictionary:

```
another_dict = {'name1' : 'x', 
                'name2' : 'y',
                'name3' : 'z'}
```

What I would like is to produce a third dictionary that looks like this:

```
third_dict = {1 : 'x', 
              2 : 'y',
              3 : 'z'}
```

The values of `my_dict` are keys in `third_dict` for the corresponding values of `another_dict`. This would be easy for me, except that the key names for the first two dictionaries are not identical. I am assuming that the key names in `another_dict` will always be a part of the those in `my_dict`, however not all of the keys in `my_dict` will have a matching key in `another_dict`.

My current, erroneous, inefficient, method:

```
    third_dict={}

    for key in my_dict:
        for sub_key in another_dict:
            if sub_key in key:
                for key in my_dict:
                    third_dict[my_dict[key]] = another_dict[sub_key]
```

EDIT: As suggested, it would be interesting to see how exceptions are handled. For instance, what if another_dict has an entry, which doesn't match an entry in my_dict or vice versa? Or what if another_dict has surplus entries?

Comment: `dict(zip(my_dict.values(), another_dict.values()))`

Comment: Interesting question. But the interesting part deals with how you want to handle non-matches and surplus matches. For example: (A) What should happen if `another_dict` has a `name4` key (no match). (B) What should hapen if `my_dict` also has a `total_name2` key (surplus matches). Perhaps you could edit your question to clarify these matters.

Comment: No exceptions are raised in any of the provided answers. The dictionary comprehension is constructed using conditions, so `for every partial_key in dict2 for every full_key in dict1 if partial_key in full_key` simply iterates over the keys in `dict1` and `dict2`, checks if `partial_key` is part of `full_key`, and if the condition does not hold, moves on without including the value in the comprehension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [dictionary comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
>>> my_dict = {'full_name1' : 1, 'full_name2' : 2, 'full_name3' : 3}
>>> another_dict = {'name1' : 'x', 'name2' : 'y', 'name3' : 'z'}
>>> {key:value for S, key in my_dict.iteritems() for s, value in another_dict.iteritems() if s in S}
{1: 'x', 2: 'y', 3: 'z'}
```

Comment: As suggested by @FMc, I edited the question to see how exceptions are handled. I up-voted your answer as it was the most concise and accurate. Perhaps you could edit it to include exception handling capability?

Comment: @user1083734 as [Dan Gittik said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473771/check-if-dictionary-key-contains-any-of-another-dictionarys-keys-and-print-matc/17473995#comment25423575_17473771) There is no need for handling `Exceptions` as none will occur, however - there is a *need* for *you* to specify what you want to happen under these conditions? If there is a duplicate name, only the latest (last to be iterated) value will be used.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
full_name1 = 'Will Smith'
full_name2 = 'Matt Damon'
full_name3 = 'Mark yMark'

name1 = 'Will'
name2 = 'Matt'
name3 = 'Mark'

my_dict = {full_name1 : 1,
           full_name2 : 2,
           full_name3 : 3}

another_dict = {name1 : 'x',
                name2 : 'y',
                name3 : 'z'}

result = {}
for sub, val in another_dict.items():   # start with the substrings
    for string, key in my_dict.items():
        if sub in string:
            result[key]=val

print(result)
```

I used `dict.items()` to make the code a bit more readable. Combined with some more clear variable names, I think that makes the logic a bit easier to follow.

docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

Could be simplified I'm sure. Note that I assumed that your words like `name1` were actually strings.

Edit: Fixed changed strings to variable names.

Comment: `namex` and `full_namex` are variables not strings. He wants to check if `namex` and `full_namex` have the same value, not the same name.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't clear about that. Mind you, if `name` and `full_name` are variables that *contain* strings, the code works the exact same way.

Comment: @enginefree I edited the question to clear this up. Apologies for my mistake, they are meant to be strings, not variables. Also, as suggested by FMc, I edited the question again to include error handling capability

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [dictionary comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) , so like

```
>>> my_dict = {'full_name1' : 1,
...            'full_name2' : 2,
...            'full_name3' : 3}
>>> 
>>> another_dict = {'name1' : 'x',
...                 'name2' : 'y',
...                 'name3' : 'z'}
>>> { y:j for x,y in my_dict.items() for i,j in another_dict.items() if i in x }

{1: 'x', 2: 'y', 3: 'z'}
```

**Edit:**

If you want an iterator instead of loading all items, you can use `dict.iteritems()` instead of `dict.items()` as suggested by InbarRose

Comment: You should use `iteritems()` instead of `items()` so that it does not load all the items into memory.

Comment: @InbarRose I didn't know that the dictionaries could return iterators. That's awesome.

Comment: My pleasure. I am surprised you were unaware, since your answer is almost identical to mine - I assumed you had a better understanding of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dictionary comprehensions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
{dict1[full_key]:dict2[partial_key] for full_key    in dict1
                                    for partial_key in dict2
                                    if  partial_key in full_key}
```

### EDIT

The `.items()` and `.iteritems()` solutions are very similar, but this solution does not load or even bind unnecessary values, and is a little more readable. The `dict(zip(dict1.values(),dict2.values()))` solution is just wrong because it depends on the dictionaries having the same keys in the same order (whereas the problem states the dictionaries' keys may differ, and any dictionaries' keys are unordered anyway...).